# How to enable Foreign Key constraint in SQLITE with Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, foreign-keys

Today I noticed that Foreign key constraint on my SQLite table does not work. After reading on Stack Overflow, I found out that this should be enabled. So, I was looking for code snippet for doing that. So far, I could only find this:

```
[self.db executeUpdate:@"PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON"];
```

But this does not seem to work for me, as compiler always complains. I saw people use this line for `FMDatabase` type (I don't even know what is it).
 So, how do I enable foreign key constraint, if I open database connection like this:

```
- (void) openDatabase
{
    const char* databaseFile = [[self pathToDatabaseFile:@"readlater.sql"] UTF8String];
    sqlite3 *connection;
    if (sqlite3_open(databaseFile, &connection) != SQLITE_OK) {
        return;
    }
    self.db = connection;
}
```

Or should it be done while creating tables?
Thank you.

Comment: The `FMDatabase` class is part of the [FMDB library](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), a thin Objective-C wrapper around the SQLite C API. Using FMDB can greatly simplify your SQLite code.

Comment: @Rob, thank you for clearing this out for me. I will read look into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using the SQLite C API directly, you must also use a C function to execute SQL commands:

```
sqlite3_exec(connection, "PRAGMA foreign_keys = on", NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Should I insert this line before each SELECT/INSERT/... statement?

Comment: What has to be done? I executed `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` at application start, as the only statement in a transaction, and in the next transaction I execute `PRAGMA foreign_keys;` and it still returns 0.

Comment: @Ixx To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: This answer ("call sqlite3_exec()") would not be the same as for your question.