# Foreign Key Constraint not Working in sqlite3 Objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, foreign-keys

I have table named `favourites`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `favourites` (
      `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
      `product_id` INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL,
      `is_favourite` BOOL,`is_sync` BOOL,
       FOREIGN KEY (product_id) references products (id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

But when insert using query, i didn't get any error in app. But when i downloaded the container and opened the DB using SQLiteBrowser and it works well.

When google i [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329379/how-to-enable-foreign-key-constraint-in-sqlite-with-objective-c) and also this won't make any change to the current scenario..

```
sqlite3_exec(objDatabase, "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON", NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

> Current sqlite3_version: 3.24.0

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlite3_exec(_DB, "PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1", NULL, NULL, NULL);
```